# Checkboxes with data update on HTML/CSS if possible

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have a form with checkboxes on HTML/CSS. And I couldn't find a tip how to make something like on this webpage: [Result I want to achieve](http://bm-holding.ru/ohrana-dom.html)

(if you scroll down a little)On this webpage there is a form with checkboxes on the right side.If you hit any of them,the values on the left side would change.So i made the form with the checkboxes but can't figure out how to make it something like this.For example on the bottom of the form add text with changing value.If you could give me a tip in which direction to dig or im forced to use JS, in this case some info would be great.Since im kinda new to this :C

Comment: Yes, you will need to use Javascript.  You should do some research on click handlers and how to show/hide/manipulate content.  As it stands, this is far too broad

Answer (score 1):

I think, based on looking at the webpage, you're looking for something like this;

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpn2fo6m/

*Note: Requires JQuery.*

JS

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
  var $dl = $('#data-list');
  if ( !$this.prop( "checked" ) ) {
    $dl.find('div[data-type="'+$this.attr('data-listtype')+'"]').remove();
  }
  else {
    $dl.append("<div data-type='"+$this.attr('data-listtype')+"'>"+$this.val()+"</div>");
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="col">
  <h2>Your order</h2>
  <p>Some general description of order</p>
  <div id="data-list"></div>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <h2>
  Checkboxes
  </h2>
  <input type="checkbox" data-listtype="1" value="Add One" />
  <input type="checkbox" data-listtype="2" value="Add Two" />
  <input type="checkbox" data-listtype="3" value="Add Three" />
  <input type="checkbox" data-listtype="4" value="Add Four" />
  <input type="checkbox" data-listtype="5" value="Add Five" />
  <input type="checkbox" data-listtype="6" value="Add Six" />
</div>
```

Essentially, what the code does here is;

1. looks for the selection (or deselection) of a checkbox.
2. Adds or removes the selected elements' value to the target.

Comment: Should also be noted that this answer requires the use of jQuery. :-)

Comment: @Colobri; Ahh yes. Thanks, I'll add that in.

Comment: Almost ^) Thanks,i just need to make that it would show only 1 value but it would change depending on checkboxes.Yay welp if i need jQuery then it will be :)) God Bless

Comment: @ExiledRain; in that case, I've edited my code. New fiddle here; https://jsfiddle.net/w84dhy3c/

Comment: Well it would just change value of checkbox.But if i want to check 3 checkboxes out of 6 and add value of each checked checkbox...? if all checkboxes have value of 1 and if i check 3 i would get 3 in result

Comment: @ExiledRain; Are the values numerical, or strings? Do you want them combined in the order the elements are in, or in the order they are selected?

Comment: oh didn't saw the comment :C
Values would be just numbers like on the example page...and if i check more checkboxes they should ADD.